# Why is this const const const declaration valid

Tags: c++, c

A friend asked me to explain why

```
const const const const const int const i = 0;
```

is valid syntax. I declined to have any thoughts on the subject. Though I'm curious if it is just a grammar thing?

Edit. Tag is C++, my friend was referencing gcc, so I should probably add the C tag.

Comment: [It’s not.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77773912987e1506)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, the subject is tagged C++, not C. -1

Comment: @Konrad. It is valid C but invalid C++. (didnt intent to delete)

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal In that case, my comment stands: the question is tagged [tag:c++]. Since these are separate languages that shouldn’t be confused, I’m not sure what your comment adds. Now the OP has added the [tag:c] tag, that changes things.

Comment: I was confused about the language in question. However I would have  expected this to translate to both c and c++. Even though the excellent answer proves otherwise.

Comment: Interestingly, g++ will generate an error for double `const` even outside C++11 mode (where it's actually allowed), but it will not complain in any way about `constexpr const` (which of course isn't _quite the same thing_, but still somewhat superfluous in the same way).

Comment: @Damon I believe that the restriction was added in C++03 as well.

Comment: @damon: `constexpr const` is something different than `const` clang emits a warning on this.

Comment: @Alex: I'm well aware that `const` alone is different from `constexpr const`. I just wonder that gcc doesn't at least warn about the latter since `constexpr` is already `const` by definition (not only runtime, but even compiletime). You can use a `constexpr` value as enumerator or template parameter, a value really can't get any more `const` than that. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From n1256:

6.7.3/4

> If the same qualiﬁer appears more than once in the same
>   speciﬁer-qualiﬁer-list,either directly or via one or more typedefs,
>   the behavior is the same as if it appeared only once.

In C++, this should give an error.

From C++03 standard:

7.1.5/1 [dcl.type]

> As a general rule, at most one type-specifier is allowed in the
>   complete decl-specifier-seq of a declaration. The only exceptions to
>   this rule are the following:
>
> — const or volatile can be combined with any other type-specifier.  However, redundant cv- qualifiers are prohibited except when introduced through the use of typedefs (7.1.3) or template type arguments (14.3), in which case the redundant cv-qualifiers are ignored.

From N3797 (C++11):

7.1.6/2 [dcl.type]

> As a general rule, at most one type-speciﬁer is allowed in the
>   complete decl-speciﬁer-seq of a declaration or in a type-speciﬁer-seq
>   or trailing-type-speciﬁer-seq. The only exceptions to this rule are
>   the following:
>
> ```
> — const can be combined with any type specifier except itself.
> ```

Comment: Same with `&`, I believe.  `typedef int& t; typedef t& u;` will mean `u` and `t` are the same type.  (Beware literal `&&` though, that's c++11)