# Is it legal to have multiple const qualifiers?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

As a result of some discussion about placement of `const`, I started to wonder if you can have multiple `const` qualifiers to the same type:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const const int a = 5;
    std::cout << a;
}
```

<sub>Don't worry, I'm not going to write code like this</sub>

Turns out, clang and MSVC accept the code with a warning, but GCC rejects it: https://godbolt.org/z/TdYnvc

Which compiler is right?

Comment: One of my favourites is `const int const * const pi = nullptr;`

Comment: `clang++ -Werror foo.cpp` if you'd prefer the warning to be an error.

Comment: @RichardCritten `const int const` isn't any more legal than `const const int` though.

Comment: Answered in [Why is this const const const declaration valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20551632/why-is-this-const-const-const-declaration-valid)

Comment: Each decl-specifier **shall appear at most once** in **a complete decl-specifier-seq**, except that long may appear twice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is ill-formed. [[dcl.type]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type#general-2)

> As a general rule, at most one [*defining-type-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type#nt:defining-type-specifier) is allowed in
> the complete [*decl-specifier-seq*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.spec.general#nt:decl-specifier-seq) of a [*declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.pre#nt:declaration) or in a
> [*defining-type-specifier-seq*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type#nt:defining-type-specifier-seq), and at most one [*type-specifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type#nt:type-specifier) is allowed
> in a [*type-specifier-seq*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type#nt:type-specifier-seq). The only exceptions to this rule are the
> following:
>
> - `const` can be combined with any type specifier except itself.
> - ...

So it's not allowed to repeat `const` literally like `const const int a = 5;`. (PS redundant cv-qualifications introduced by typedefs are allowed and would be ignored).

Answer (score 12):

> Is it legal to have multiple const qualifiers?
>
> ```
> const const int a = 5;
> ```

No. The rule was already covered by other fine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66387015/2079303) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386940/2079303).

Note that this applies only to the grammar, and not to the type system in general. You can apply const to a const type alias:

```
using T = const int;
const T a = 5; // OK
```

Multiple cv qualifiers combined this way "collapse" into one.

> Which compiler is right?

In the sense of "which compiler conforms to the standard": All of them.

Compilers are *not* required to reject ill-formed programs, nor are they required to accept them. Since all compilers issue a diagnostic message, they all conform to the standard. Quote:

> [intro.compliance.general]
>
> Although this document states only requirements on C++ implementations, those requirements are often easier to understand if they are phrased as requirements on programs, parts of programs, or execution of programs.
> Such requirements have the following meaning:
>
> - If a program contains no violations of the rules in [lex] through [thread] and [depr], a conforming implementation shall, within its resource limits as described in [implimits], accept and correctly execute<sup>5</sup> that program.
> - If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an occurrence of a construct described in this document as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support that construct, **a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message**.
> - If a program contains a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is required, this document places no requirement on implementations with respect to that program.
>
> <sup>5) “Correct execution” can include undefined behavior</sup>

Accepting an ill-formed program intentionally is called a "language extension".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of difference between "reject" and "diagnostic required".

Answer (score 8):

GCC is correct.

A compiler should not compile the code. The reason is explicit [[dcl.type.cv]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.type.cv#1):

There are two *cv-qualifiers*, `const` and `volatile`. Each *cv-qualifier* shall appear at most once in a *cv-qualifier-seq*.

You *are* allowed to add `const` to an already `const` type (template programming would be difficult if this were not possible). But you can't write `const const` as per the above rule.

Comment: As a sidenote, clang states *“Where we support extensions above and beyond what the standard officially allows, we make an effort to explicitly call this out in the code and emit warnings about it”*. I guess we see there an example of this kind of deviation from strict conformance, and as promised they do emit a warning about it.